# What is the maximum number of clones that can be saved?

Tags: badland

I just finished BadLand with the score of 223 clones saved.
I really want to know how much could I push it to the limits of this game.
In other words, what is the maximum number of clones that I can save?

Comment: The [Badland Forums](http://forum.badlandgame.com/index.php) have a [Save the Clones Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FuXQhVRjydF5S6Yt1jF7RK8VvJGE5XUF5-kcKQqKMy0/edit), but it seems to be locked unfortunately.